# TFS 2012 is not recognizing a file as having been deleted

Tags: resharper-8.0

I am working with another developer on an applciation. Whenever one of us deletes a file that has been pulled down on the other workstation. TFS doesn't seem to pass down the files as deleted on the next get request.

Short story: I delete file -> Check in -> Team mate does get -> gets build errors due to the files still being on his local disk

Anyone know what we are doing wrong?

We are using local workspaces. We are checking in the delete. Everything we are doing is happening in Visual Studio. Not in a file explorer anywhere.

UPDATE:  It has something to do with resharper 8 and TFS not playing well together. When I move a file or safe delete a file with resharper commands TFS doesn't recognize it (the green lock sign is not in solution explorer).

Comment: Are you pending the delete?  Are you checking in the delete?  Are you using local or server workspaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to `check in your csproj file`, he contains all files included in your project, your another developper get latest old csproj, so you find your file